# General Licensing Template?

Tags: compiler-construction, open-source, programming-languages

As I am developing a project, a webpage that should enable people to program a compiler for the WIP ICETee language. Doesn't matter now, but I need a license that is like an open source license. It should furthermore make it possible that people who sell programs written in this language should give a certain amount of the price to the language developers that gets split up relatively to all the programmers helping.
Is there anything like that?

I'd be happy for every hint possible and also for linking to another question if it is answered and about the same thing.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about legal advice for licensing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no standard and widely available licence like that. As soon as you bring money into it you also bring lawyers into it.

You could start with a GPL or similar licence, and then dual licence the code. Anyone who wanted to make money out of it would have to get a commercial licence from you and you could put any terms you like into that. For that you will need lawyers, not helpful hints from a place like this.

Comment: Well that was already very helpful to me. Thanks for that, since I haven't really considered a dual license, but now it makes perfect sense why to use it like that.